# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "table_name" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using PostgreSQL 10, Spring Boot 2.2.7.RELEASE, and pgAdmin 4 for Postgres GUI

I have the following entity class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"TB03_TABLE_A\"")
public class VersionData {

    private int id;
    private String version;
    private String dataType;
    private int min;
    private int max;
    private String possibleValues;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "\"TB03_TABLE_A_seq\"", name = "table_a_id_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "table_a_id_seq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "\"ID\"", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Column(name = "\"VERSION\"")
    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }
    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @Column(name = "\"DATATYPE\"")
    public String getDataType() {
        return dataType;
    }
    public void setDataType(String dataType) {
        this.dataType = dataType;
    }

    @Column(name = "\"MIN\"")
    public int getMin() {
        return min;
    }
    public void setMin(int min) {
        this.min = min;
    }

    @Column(name = "\"MAX\"")
    public int getMax() {
        return max;
    }
    public void setMax(int max) {
        this.max = max;
    }

    @Column(name = "\"POSSIBLE_VALUES\"")
    public String getPossibleValues() {
        return possibleValues;
    }
    public void setPossibleValues(String possibleValues) {
        this.possibleValues = possibleValues;
    }


}
```

I have created table "TB03_TABLE_A" and sequence for the ID column "TB03_TABLE_A_seq" using the GUI pgAdmin 4

I have the following service Class to persist data to the entity

```
@Service
public class VersionDataImpl{
    @Autowired
    private VersionDataRepo dataRepo;
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public void copyVersion(String newBranch, String sourceBranch) {

        copyVersionData(newBranch, sourceBranch);


    }

    @Transactional
    private void copyVersionData(String newBranch, String sourceBranch) {
        List<VersionData> versionDataLs = mddRepo.getDataByVersion(sourceBranch);

        for (VersionData  versionData : versionDataLs) {
            VersionData mdd = new VersionData();
            versionData.setDataType(mddData.getDataType());
            versionData.setMax(mddData.getMax());
            versionData.setMin(mddData.getMin());
            versionData.setPossibleValues(mddData.getPossibleValues());
            versionData.setVersion(newBranch);
            //dataRepo.insertBranchData();
            em.persist(versionData);
        }

    }

}
```

I have the following repository class :

```
@Repository
public interface VersionDataRepo extends JpaRepository<VersionData, Integer>{

    String insertBranch = "INSERT INTO public.\"TB03_TABLE_A\"(\"VERSION\", \"DATATYPE\", \"MIN\", \"MAX\", \"POSSIBLE_VALUES\")\r\n" + 
            "VALUES ( :version, :datatype, :min, :max, :possibleValues)";

    @Query(nativeQuery = true,value = insertBranch)
    void insertBranchData();
}
```

If I am performing insert operation using query, I am able to insert data.

But if I use Persist method in EntityManager, I am getting the following error :

```
2020-05-17 20:20:27.854  WARN 25832 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
2020-05-17 20:20:27.854 ERROR 25832 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "myschema.tb03_mdd_data" does not exist
  Position: 13
2020-05-17 20:20:27.865 ERROR 25832 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "tb03_mdd_data" does not exist
  Position: 13
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2533) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2268) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:313) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:448) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:369) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:159) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:125) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.4.3.jar:na]
```

Where am I going wrong with? Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue before. The best thing is to **create a class with the table name that you wants to creates**. This causes because, your table name and class name is different. Just remove **@Table** annotation and use class name as table name. This annotation didn't detected by the spring-boot itself. As a result no point of using it. I think, already table with name **version_data** must be created on your database.

Comment: I tried creating Class name with the table name I created in Postgres. Still I am facing the error as "Relation doesn't exist"

Comment: Then this error must be in another class. Remove @Table annotation of all the classes and rerun the program. This isn't cause to table creation. It still creates table in the database with the class name.

Answer (score 0):

You're using schema 'public.' in your raw SQL, whereas you're using 'myschema.' in the ORM.

Check your connection settings - you may not have provided the schema (and for example might be attempting to insert into the 'postgres' schema.

If you're using the admin account (which you absolutely categorically should NOT) you may be on the wrong schema.  Related to this you can provide a default schema for your user, otherwise you'll need to switch schemas etc.

One way to find out is programmatically - e.g. ((SessionFactoryImplementor)sessionFactory).getSettings().getDefaultSchemaName();

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience! I have edited my error trace now. Previously I tried by providing Schema and i added that error trace. Even after removing the Schema,I am getting the same error